# Как сделать многопоточный запрос?

Tags: python

Есть переменная id,равная 5\n6\n7\n8. Содержимое переменной может быть разным.
Далее мы отправляем POST запрос,он уже готов.
Нужно реализовать многопоток этого запроса

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под многопоточным запросом?

Comment: @gil9red, Бот берёт данные от пользователя и через запрос чекает их. Одиночный чек сделан, вот вопрос с многопотоком (массчеком). Я не знаю, как его сделать

Comment: Смотрите в сторону threadpool, например https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor